# Troca de informações entre classes Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, classes, multithreading

Como posso trocar informações entre duas classes diferentes? Preciso passar dados de uma para a outra. Cada classe está sendo executada em um processo diferente.

Um exemplo da estrutura, o código está muito grande, então vai ai um exemplo, a única diferença do código real é o que tem dentro das classes. Preciso comunicar a `funcao01` e a `funcao02`, por exemplo.

```
class Aplicativo():

    def funcao01(self):
        print("teste 01")


class Aplicativo2():
    def funcao02(self):
        print("teste 02")

App = Aplicativo()
App2 = Aplicativo2()

def Telas():
    App.funcao01()

def Comunicacao():
    App2.funcao02()

p = Process(target=Telas)
p1 = Process(target=Comunicacao)



def main():

    p.start()
    p1.start()
    p.join()
    p1.join()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Pode [edit] a sua pergunta e adicionar o código? São *processos* distintos ou *threads* distintas?

Comment: Fiz a edição da pergunta!

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss você sabe como implementar essas classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um grande  problema do código acima é que ele não está usando "classes" - ele está fazendo a declaração de funções no corpo de uma classe - do jeito que está, elas **não** são "métodos", são funções mesmo, que não sabem nada da classe dentro da qual foram declaradas. Isso acaba gerando um namespace artíficial, que funciona para quem vai chamar essas funções de fora, mas fica bem estranho para quando essas "funções dentro da classe" tiverem que chamar umas as outras, ou compartilhar um "atributo": elas terão que ter como prefixo o nome da classe por extenso.

A forma mais apropriada de fazer isso seria criar um método `__init__` nas classes, e colocar a classe em si como target dos processos - desta forma vocẽ vai ter uma instância "zerada" de cada classe em cada processo.

Talvez seja interessante você dar uma lida em alguma documentação e entender melhor como funciona isso. Esse artigo parece ser um bom começo (não li com atenção, mas parece ter o básico) http://pythonclub.com.br/introducao-classes-metodos-python-basico.html

Se achar complicado usar classes e métodos de forma que faça sentido, lembre-se que Python não obriga você a fazer uso das mesmas quando a sua arquitetura não precisa disso: você pode usar funções simples. No seu exemplo de código mesmo, as próprias funções `Telas` e `Comunicacao` não tem nenhum motivo para chamar outra função dentro das classes - poderiam executar a tarefa diretamente.

Depois que você arrumar isso: a forma de comunicar dados entre processos distintos é usando as classes `Multiprossecing.Queue` e `Multiprocessing.Pipe` - seu uso com um pequeno exemplo está documentado aqui: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

O seu exemplo de código ficou tão mínimo que não dá para saber o que você gostaria de comunicar de um lado para outro então qualquer exemplo que eu criasse aqui seria equivalente ao que está na documentação oficial do Python, acima.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, já esclareceu algumas das dúvidas, vou dar uma lida nos links que passou!